# Compiler error when calling async Sub with TaskFactory

Tags: vb.net

A helper method to run Async calls in a synchronised way throws a compiler error.

VB.NET, VisualStudio 2019, .NET Framework 4.6, 
Link to compiler error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc31143

```vb
Private Shared ReadOnly _taskFactory As TaskFactory = New TaskFactory(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
Shared Sub RunSync(ByVal func As Func(Of Task))
    _taskFactory.StartNew(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
End Sub
```

Call:

```vb
CLHelper.RunSync(Sub() test())
```

Method:

```vb
Async Sub test()
    Await doSomethingAsync()
End Sub
```

CLHelper.RunSync(Sub() test()) brings the compiler error BC36680: Method '' does not have a signature compatible with delegate <'delegatename'>

Comment: You are trying to pass a sub as a function. Shared Sub RunSync(ByVal func As Func(Of Task)). Change it to sub

Comment: You never write `Async Sub` except for event handlers that need to use `Await`.

Comment: I don't get it. The async method "test()" is already passed as Sub() to the void RunSync-method.

Comment: So the solution is to get the method signature changed to "Async Function test() As Task", like @Renat mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change `test` method to be `Function`, to reconcile it's signature with `RunSync` call:

```
Async Function test() As Task
    Await doSomethingAsync()
End Function
```

Comment: I can't change the method signature.